# postgres: Converting '' into NULLS

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to run this query to change my latitude coordinates, which is saved as  text into a double precision

```
ALTER TABLE mapdata ALTER COLUMN lat TYPE double precision USING (lat::double precision);
```

However, I keep getting this error: `invalid input syntax for type double precision: ""`

My assumption is that there is a blank entry and that postgres doesn't know to treat it as a double precision. How would I make this out to be a `NULL` or is there another way I can approach this to turn my `lat` column into a `double precision`? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried UPDATE mapdata SET lat = NULL WHERE lat = "";

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options:

1. you change the empty strings in the original data to NULLs and then change the type
2. you handle them while changing the type

The first one would be a simple

```
UPDATE table SET col=NULL where col='';
```

but this naturally takes time and is a bit unnecessary since you're changing the type after that.

Second way is to handle the empty strings while converting

```
ALTER TABLE mapdata
  ALTER COLUMN lat TYPE double precision
    USING (NULLIF(lat, '')::double precision);
```

The `NULLIF` will return NULL if the lat column is an empty string, otherwise it'll return the lat column value. This will be a lot more efficient than to first change the source data.